# igraph print vertex attributes R

Tags: r, igraph

How do I print out all the attributes for the nodes in my vertex sequence?

Given graph **g**, create an igraph vertex sequence with one vertex:

```
> (V(g)[1])
+ 1/12761 vertex, named:
[1] 18kPq7GPye-YQ3LyKyAZPw
```

Where *18kPq7GPye-YQ3LyKyAZPw* is the vertex name.
However, the vertices in the graph have other attributes as well:

```
> vertex_attr_names(g)
 [1] "name"  "realname"   "color"   "votes_funny"
```

How do I print out **all the attributes** for the nodes in my vertex sequence?

Comment: `vertex.attributes(g)` maybe?  Just a guess

Comment: It would be helpful to include a small [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data. Are you just looking for `vertex_attr`?

Comment: Everybody wants a small reproducible example with sample data. The MIT   guy always points people here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example    Really, though I think this is straight-forward enough without the runnable sample.

Answer (score 1):

Ah snap! As soon as I posted the question, I found the answer:

```
> V(g)[[1]]
+ 1/12761 vertex, named:
                    name realname color yelping_since votes_funny votes_useful votes_cool review_count fans
1 18kPq7GPye-YQ3LyKyAZPw   Russel   red            NA         166          278        245
```

Use **double-brackets**! [[ ]]